# Entity Framework Core one to many related data navigation property is always empty

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here; I'm using .Net 5 with Entity Framework Core. The problem is that the foreign key is correct, but the associated navigation property is always empty and has no data. Do I have to do something with the fluent framework, or do something special with my includes?

I have 3 simplified entities and a database context method in this example, the project is much too large to include entirely. In the method, `CalendarEvents` is a `DbSet`:

```
public class CalendarEvent: IJsonSerializable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the personnel associated with this event
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<SchedulePerson> SchedulePeople { get; set; } = new List<SchedulePerson>();
}

public class SchedulePerson : IJsonSerializable, ICloneable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public virtual CalendarEvent AssociatedCalendarEvent { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IJsonSerializable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SchedulePerson> AssociatedSchedulePeople { get; set; } = new List<SchedulePerson>();
}

public class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CalendarEvent> CalendarEvents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SchedulePerson> SchedulePeople { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<VibrationContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public CalendarEvent GetEvent(int calendarEventId)
    {
        var currentCalEvent = this.CalendarEvents.Where(x => x.Id == calendarEventId);
        var dummy1 = currentCalEvent.FirstOrDefault();
        var dummy2 = currentCalEvent.Include(calEvent => calEvent.SchedulePeople).ToList();
        var dummy3 = currentCalEvent.Include(calEvent => calEvent.SchedulePeople).ThenInclude(people => people.Employee).ToList();
        return currentCalEvent.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In this case `Employee` is the associated navigation property, and the associated key `EmployeeId`, is correct. For the moment I've added extra logic that will populate each employee per schedule person separately, manually based on the foreign key `EmployeeId`, when I get the event, but I'd rather not have to add logic like that each time. If that's something unavoidable then that's fine, but I'd like to do things properly and let Entity Framework Core handle as much as possible.

For additional context:

- `SchedulePerson -> CalendarEvent` is a many-to-one relationship
- `Employee -> SchedulePerson` is a many-to-one relationship

In other words a calendar event can contain many schedule persons, but a schedule person can only be associated with one calendar event.

Employee can be associated with many schedule persons, but each schedule person is only associated with one employee.

There should only be one employee for each real person, but there can be multiple `SchedulePersons` for each real person.

Thank you for your help and let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Also if anything else looks bad or wrong in these code snippets please let me know.

Edit, this is what I have to do if I want to get the employees in my request:

```
    private void UpdateEmployeeContents(CalendarEvent calendarEvent)
    {
        foreach (SchedulePerson person in calendarEvent.SchedulePeople)
        {
            person.Employee = this.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == person.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with clean project containing just the simplified model shown? `dummy3` (using `Include` + `ThenInclude`) is the intended way to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks I'll go ahead and try to replicate that in a simple git repo then paste the link here.

Comment: Based on your code snippets, I have created a sample on my side (without using the IJsonSerializable and ICloneable interface, you could explain more detail about it), it seems that it could load the related data, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svGUi.png). Since, you are querying the database based the field value, I suggest you check the database first, whether it contains the related data. Besides, I suggest you check the "this.Employees", whether it is queried from the database and contains the related data. Might be you could try to directly query the data from the DB context.